# sen2r file path error (UPDATED)

Tags: r, sentinel-2, file-path, sen2cor

UPDATE: I think I've solved the problem. I created a bogus temp folder for my nonexistent L1C images

```
l1c_safe<-tempfile(pattern = "safe_")
```

and passed this to the `path_l1c= argument`. I still don't understand why the error occurred since the function runs just fine with `path_tiles` and `path_merged` set to NA.

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm using sen2r to process some sentinel-2 images I've already downloaded, but I'm having issues with the `path_l1c` term. The starting images are in the SAFE format, and all in one folder defined by `path_l2a`. When I run this function:

```
sen2r(
  gui=FALSE,
  preprocess= TRUE, #Whether or not to preprocess L1c data
  s2_levels= "l2a", #S-2 levels required for output
  sel_sensor= c("s2a","s2b"), #Sensors to be used
  online= FALSE, #Aquire online data (True) or work with already downloaded data (false)
  server= "scihub", #Data sources: "scihub" or "gcloud"
  order_lta= TRUE, #Whether to order products from the long term archive
  downloader= "builtin",
  overwrite_safe= FALSE, #overwrite downloaded SAFE files?
  rm_safe= "no", #Remove SAFE files after processing?
  max_cloud_safe= 10, #Maximum acceptable cloud coverage
  step_atmcorr= "auto", #How to obtain L2C products.
  sen2cor_use_dem= FALSE,
  sen2cor_gipp= NA,
  timewindow= 2022-01-01, 2022-12-31, #Start and end dates
  timeperiod= "full", #or "seasonal" to acquire images of the same months from multiple years
  extent= boundaries, #shapefile of subset image.
  extent_name= "ALT", #file name to be appended to cropped images
  s2tiles_selected= NA,
  s2orbits_selected= NA,
  list_prods= "BOA", #list of products to be processed
  list_indices= c("ARI","ARVI","Chlred-edge","EVI","GNDVI",
                  "MCARI","MSAVI2","MSI","NDFI","NDMI","NDRE",
                  "NDVI","NDVIre","NDWI","NMDI","SAVI","SIPI1",
                  "TCARI","WDRVI"),
  index_source= "BOA",
  clip_on_extent= TRUE,
  extent_as_mask= TRUE,
  reference_path= NA,
  res= 10,
  unit= "Meter",
  proj= "6346",
  resampling= "near",
  resampling_scl= "near",
  outformat= "GTiff",
  index_datatype= "Float32",
  compression= "DEFLATE",
  overwrite= FALSE,
  path_l1c= NA,
  path_l2a= "E:/Thesis/S-2 Imagery/sen2R_Processing/L2A_SAFE",
  path_tiles= NA,
  path_merged= NA,
  path_out= out_dir_1,
  path_indices= out_dir_2,
  path_subdirs= TRUE,
  thumbnails= TRUE,
  log= NA,
  parallel= 6,
  processing_order= "by_groups",
)
```

I get this error code:

> Error in list.files(pm$path_l1c, "\.SAFE$", full.names = TRUE) :
> invalid 'path' argument

All of my images are L2A, so I didn't specify a filepath for L1c. Another user had the same problem, which the developer said was an issue with the code, resolved as of Feb 2019:
https://github.com/ranghetti/sen2r/issues/151

I'm using the most current version of the package. Can anyone offer advice? I can't produce any outputs at the moment, and I'd rather not download all the images again if I can avoid it.